# Why are my Azure triggered WebJobs never run successfully?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I have a few Azure WebJobs that run to completion, once my business logic is done I call `await StopAsync(stoppingToken);`

However, Azure Portal continues to show their status as "Running" until eventually the jobs terminated after the default 120 second timeout.

How can I correctly tell Azure Portal/Kudu that the job is in fact finished?

Here is an example that shows the issue:

```
namespace MyService
{
    public class MyService : BackgroundService
    {
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            // same issue whether or not I call this:
            await StopAsync(stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share some code with us please?

Comment: @Thomas I've added an example to the question

Comment: Also I just tried creating a worker service using the template that comes with VS2022 and it has the same issue...

Comment: I am experienced the same issue. Same job, when I run it manually (start button in Azure portal), finishes correctly, showing: "Ran a minute ago", but when it's triggered by timer, Azure doesn't know it's finished

Answer (score 0):

A week after posting this question my jobs are now mysteriously completing successfully even though no changes were made, I assume someone at Microsoft fixed something on their end.

Comment: No wait I lied, my jobs are returning as successful if they throw an exception instead of just finishing...